# C++ define function syntax with rand

Tags: c++

I am working on a class assignment with starter code and included is this syntax that I've never seen before.

`#define EVENT() (rand() % 2 > 0.5)`

Can someone tell me what this does? Does it return something? I know the define is a macro that has a function called EVENT(), but what does the `(rand() % 2 > 0.5)` bit mean? If I use EVENT() in the code somewhere, do I treat it as a void function that just evaluates to that statement?

Comment: It's [a macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace). Read about them in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: This is somewhat bogus, as `rand() % 2` is an integer but it is being relationally compared with floating point for no apparent reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wherever EVENT() is used in the source code , the preprocessor substitutes EVENT() with rand() % 2 > 0.5 which will return a random 1 or 0, 1 if the rand() result was odd and 0 if the result was even.

Comment: If rand() is even, the statement evaluates to 0, which is less than 0.5, so what would it return in this case? Nothing? If rand() returns an odd, the remainder would be 1, so it seems that it returns only 1 ever?

Comment: > will return 1 if rand() % 2 is odd and 0 if it's even , so we will have random numbers from 0 - 1 range. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs do you not know what `something > 0.5` does?

Comment: I thought I did , it returns 0 or 1 depending on whether it's true or not ?